# Css position fixed not working with display flex

Tags: html, css

I am trying to layout my page using `flexbox`.
I want the right child to be fixed and the left one to scroll.

below is the markup.

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
}

.child1 {
   position:fixed;
   order: 1;
   height: 300px;
   background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
   order: 2;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">1</div>
  <div class="child2">2</div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to make the `child1` static while `child2` scrolls down.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a mock up of what you want, it is difficult for me to tell from the description. Are child1 and child2 adjacent to each other?

Comment: When you use `position: fixed` it takes the element out of the document flow, therefore nullifying the flexbox layout. The `position: fixed` should be applied to a child element inside `child1`, if you want to achieve what you have described.

Comment: @Avocado. child1 and child2 are side by side since I displayed the parent as flex.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, you want to use `position:sticky` to achieve the layout.

Here's the HTML structure

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1">Child 1 content goes here</div>
  <div class="child child2">
    <div class="sticky">
      Child 2 content goes here
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.child {
  flex: 0 1 48%;
  border: 5px solid #ececec;
}

.child1 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.child2 {
  position: sticky; // will keep the position of the div stuck
  top: 0; // this will specify when do you want the position sticky to take effect from the top
}
```

Have linked the codepen https://codepen.io/backslashr/pen/abvzQmo